# Unable to make an applet work in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, applet

I am a complete noob.
I am just learning to program using java.
I followed a tutorial and created the following applet in IntelliJ Idea in my brother's computer:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class MyFirstApplet extends JApplet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("To climb a ladder, start at the bottom rung.", 20, 90);
    }
}
```

When i try to run this , the IDE shows:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\Abhirup_2\AppData\Local\Temp\AppletPage6525114136327939228.html" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:838)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:82)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1103)
    at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1074)
    at sun.applet.Main.run(Main.java:156)
    at sun.applet.Main.main(Main.java:98)
    at sun.applet.AppletViewer.main(AppletViewer.java:1257)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However it runs well in my friend's computer in eclipse. 
Please help.

UPDATE:
There is a single account and that is my brother's acoount. I am using that and being the only account it should have admiistrator rights if I am not wrong.

Comment: Are you using your own account on your brothers pc? If you are using your own account it is possible it has limited rights and that's why you are seeing the security exception.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use an applet policy file which grants permission to run as a local applet and set it in your Run/Debug configuration in the "Policy File" field.

It should have at minimum the following:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
}
```

Or you can use the default one provided by IntelliJ in the application bin directory called **appletviewer.policy**

Comment: Thanks! I found it needed a semicolon added after the closing }